# An exercise on lattices

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

How to show that $L = \{(x,y,x)\in\mathbb{Z}^3 : 2x + 3y + 4z\equiv 0\pmod 7\}$ is a lattice?

Comment: Hint: The fact that $L$ is embedded in a larger lattice takes away the condition for a lattice that's usually the hardest to verify.

Comment: What is the definition of lattice?

Comment: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group))

Answer (score 1):

1. $L$ is discrete because it is embedded in the larger discrete lattice $\mathbb{Z}^3$
2. It is 3-dimensional because it contains the three linearly independent vectors $(0,1,1)$, $(1,0,3)$, and $(2,1,0)$.
3. Suppose that $(a,b,c)$ is an element of $L$, so that $2a + 3b + 4c \equiv 0$. Then for an integer $k$, we have that $2(ka) + 3(kb) + 4(kc) \equiv k(0) \equiv 0$, and so $(ka,kb,kc)$ is also in $L$.
4. Suppose that $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$ are two elements in $L$. Then $2a + 3b + 4c \equiv 0 \equiv 2d + 3e + 4f \implies 2(a + d) + 3(b + e) + 4(c + f) \equiv 0$, so that $(a + d, b + e, c + f)$ is also in $L$.

Thus $L$ is a dimension-3 discrete additive subgroup.